# How to tag a function?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I don't know how to "tag" my function in my data pack. Right now I use the function command in repeating command blocks, but how would I tag it so I don't need them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create the tag in the data pack, just like you created the function. The path is: `tags/functions/tick.json`

That file has to have a content like this: `{"values":["<namespace>:<name>"]}`, where `<namespace>` and `<name>` of course reference your function.

You can add more functions by appending `,"<namespace>:<name>"` before `]}`.

This will by default not overwrite ticked functions of other datapacks (but you could, if you wanted to).

Here are the wiki pages for [functions](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Function#Tags) ([archive](https://minecraft.wiki/w/index.php?title=Function&oldid=1292387#Tags)), [data packs](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Data_pack#Folder_structure) ([archive](https://minecraft.wiki/w/index.php?title=Data_pack&oldid=1294201#Folder_structure)) and [tags](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tag#JSON_format) ([archive](https://minecraft.wiki/w/index.php?title=Tag&oldid=1292388#JSON_format)), each link goes to the paragraph you need.