# Want to have text appear each time a player joins on my server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-redstone

So first off, my goal is to have [Server] say something whenever a person joins my server. I was going to do this using the .mcfunction command, where you type /function .... in game, and it saves as a .mcfunction in your data folder.

Is there a way I can do this? Will it stay active 24/7 so that whenever a player joins it will automatically say something and i wont have to manually input a command.

Comment: note that i'm trying to do this with the fairly new functions added in 1.12 (i'm playing on 1.15 atm), not with command blocks in-game

Comment: The fundamentals there still apply.  Yeah, the `execute` command needs to be updated to the new syntax, but it's pretty much the same now as it was for that question (looks like 1.8 maybe?), just in a function file instead of command blocks.

Comment: Please only ask one question per… well, question. I edited out the second one. If you ask it in a new question, please provide a lot more detail about what you mean. Also, I recommend reading the wiki page about functions, it's not at all the case that you create those from within the game.

Comment: There is no advancement trigger for joining a world, so the answer over there is actually the best one. The top answer was apparently from before 1.9, I updated it it to 1.13+ now. It works exactly the same in functions, you just need a ticking function, see here for more information on that: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/342343/171580

Comment: if i'm doing this with a function, do i need to do anything special to identify the command as "active repeating command" or "chain command block" or can i just copy all the commands from the link above

thanks